# for-loop don't work with cordova

Tags: for-loop, cordova

i have a querymobile/cordova app. i have a function with a for-loop. if i try it in my browser, it works perfekt, but on my tablet, he stops before the loop starts. i don't get an error in eclipse.

here's my code

```
    function listPlan(){

        alert("try to parse ics");
        cal = $.parseIcs('sdcard/ical/'+aktFile);
        console.log(cal);

        alert('daten anzeigen');
        for (var i=0; i<cal.event.length; i++) {

            alert(i);
            $('#roosters').append('<div data-role="collapsible"><h3>'+cal.event[i].dtstart[0].value+'</h3></div>');

        }

        $('#roosters').collapsibleset('refresh');

    }
```

Comment: I'd say the problem comes from $.parseIcs not returning what's expected and cal.event not being defined. Where's this function coming from? Do you look for errors in the logcat tab in eclipse?

Comment: yes, logcat. parseIcs() comes from an external script. i said already, that the script works in the browser. that is what i don't understand

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can access files on the sdcard using ajax calls.

Try with `cal = $.parseIcs('file:///sdcard/ical/'+aktFile);`

If it still does not work, maybe should you use the phonegap file api to get the file instead?

---

### Edit:

I've performed a few tests to check access to files on the sdcard with ajax calls on Gingerbread, Jelly bean and KitKat using different urls:

- 'sdcard/test.txt' (like you're using in your initial code) : does not
  work on my test devices
- '/sdcard/test.txt' : works in gingerbread and jelly bean
- 'file:///sdcard/test.txt' : works in gingerbread and jelly bean
- 'file://sdcard/test.txt' : works in gingerbread but not jelly bean

none of those worked with kitkat (seems that the new webview added some restrictions).

So it seems that unless you tested with kitkat, using $.parseIcs should work.

Maybe the problem comes from some character encoding in your file? You could try to add some debugging code in the parseCalendar function to know why no event is added during the parsing.

### Edit2

Surprisingly, on my kitkat device, xhr access to files on the sdcard requires to add the line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in androidmanifest.xml

Comment: still don't work. i don't think that would be the problem, cause if the parseIcs() can't open the file, i'll get an error and i still get "alert('daten anzeigen');", but then programm stops

Comment: one more: console.log(cal); gives (objekt)(objekt) and thats good

Comment: have you tried to console.log for cal.event and cal.event.length? Or maybe console.log(JSON.stringify(cal))

Comment: .length = 0, the problem is really the path. i don't understand, because i don't get an error from the parsing script, but if i use the path inside the app, it works^^ so i have to look, how it works with the cordova get file. thanks for this idea. why haven't i done this by my own? :D

Comment: thats it. with the 2nd option it works. that was the only one i didn't try by myself. thank you :)